# hide "one of the attribute label name" in layered navigation

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

see "shop by" on left side in above link.

there you can see 3 values....

1)black[remove]
2)white 1
3)white 3

I want to hide black [remove] option from layered navigation, i don't want to delete it.

please help me to find solutiion.

thanks in advance.

hide "one of the attribute label name" in layered navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove some option directly in your theme template (dirty hack):

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\filter.phtml`

after line
    `<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>`

add line
    `<?php if($_item->getLabel() == 'black') continue; ?>`

Comment: i will try your solution and tell you soon....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to set the `Use In Search Results Layered Navigation` value in attribute edit for your Contrast Ratio

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: i want to hide only label-name "black", but i want to display "contrast ratio"

under layered navigation with label names "white 1, white 3 but not black"

Comment: You should delete it from the values of the attribute or else you shoud set the value of Use In Search Results Layered Navigation as Filterable(with no results) do not assign any products to the black(remove) else by custom coding

Comment: I have to assign products to black in admin panel. i need to do that.

but i want to hide only that "black", if i set =Filterable(with no results) , entire attribute will not visible. need for only one balue ="black"